# ¿Por qué "mogollón" adquirió el significado de "mucho", "gran cantidad" y "jaleo"?

Tags: etimología, definiciones, significado

Las ediciones de 1970 y anteriores del Diccionario de la Lengua definen (con mínimas diferencias) **mogollón** como

> 1. **Holgazán, vago, gorrón**
> 2. **Entremetimiento de uno donde no le llaman o no es convidado.**

Pero las ediciones de 2001 y actual del [Diccionario de la Lengua Española](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PWD37Gs) recogen

> 1. adj. p. us. **holgazán**.
> 2. adj. p. us. **gorrón** (‖ que vive a costa ajena).
> 3. m. coloq. **Gran cantidad o gran número.**
> 4. m. coloq. **Lío, jaleo.**
> 5. adv. coloq. **mucho.**

¿Por qué fue adquiriendo esos nuevos significados, y en fechas tan recientes?

Answer (score 1):

Buen descubrimiento. Una palabra que yo me creía moderna pero que es más vieja que el andar hacia adelante. Efectivamente, en 1611 ya Covarrubias lo definía así:

> MOGOLLON. Este es un termino antiguo y muy usado, y poco entendido: a algunos les parece sinificar el corderillo que ha quedado sin madre, y acude a mamar a las demas ovejas la leche de los propios suyos: y dixose del verbo Latino *mulgeo*, que quiere dezir *ordeñar*; y en rigor, segun lo dicho está corrompido el vocablo de *mulgollon*. El padre Guadix le tiene por Arabigo: y dize, que vale tanto como comer sin escorar, comer de mogollon. Otros dizen, que viene del nombre Mugali, que significa bullicioso y entremetido en Arabigo, y tal es el que se sienta a mesa agena sin que le combiden.

Curiosa definición sin duda, pero que ya define la expresión "de mogollón", que se puede encontrar en textos tan antiguos como este:

> *La hortolana la myró y le dyxo: "¿Allá donde os cavalgastes no pudystes yr a paryr, syno después de hechos vuestros malos rrecauos, salys os a paryr por los campos, y myentra estarés mala que os den de comer **de mogollón**? Aquí no ay qué comáys -poné vuestras haldas encyerra y tornaos a la vylla para paryr en hora mala. Apretá los dyentes; apretá y enpuxá rrezyo -que en ese serón pary yo sola este hijo myo y de my marydo- y no hecho a hurtadyllas."*
>
> - Anónimo, "La corónica de Adramón", España (c. 1492)

Este sentido de la expresión ha sido el predominante en la expresión escrita hasta hace relativamente poco. La primera coincidencia de "mogollón" usado con el sentido de "mucho" aparece en el CREA:

> *Dijo que iba a echar conmigo unos diítas de descanso, pero vaya con el descanso: tenía que ver a un señor (el teléfono), y luego otra cosa de los negocios (el teléfono), y conferencia con Bilbao y comer con otros dos señores (el teléfono): fíjate tú que descanso el suyo, en vez de darle un martillazo al teléfono y quedarse un poquito tranquilo, ¿no?; él ya con un malhumó grande y tomando pastillas pa los nervios cuando él mismo se estaba echando encima aquel **mogollón** de trabajo y se había ido a Málaga a descansar conmigo. Y eso dicen que es bueno, andar como los locos, que ya parece tonto el que no anda como un loco y eso es el pogrezo, o sea, el adelanto.*
>
> - Fernando Quiñones, "Las mil noches de Hortensia Romero", España (1979)

Nótese que este texto está escrito imitando el habla, por lo que la expresión surgiría bastante antes. Sobre la adición de nuevos significados a la expresión, no encuentro nada pero me atrevería a decir que es una consecuencia lógica de las anteriores. Según el CORDE, el uso mayoritario de la palabra era en su forma "[de mogollón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PWD37Gs)" significado "de balde", "de gorra". Cuando una persona come gratis, lo normal es que active lo que yo llamo "el modo buffet libre" y se atiborre a comer como si no hubiera un mañana. A fin de cuentas, otros están pagando por su comida, y no sabe cuándo se verá en una similar. Por tanto, una persona que come "de mogollón" es normal que coma "un mogollón".

Sobre la otra acepción, la de "jaleo", tampoco es tan nueva, fíjate que Covarrubias ya identificaba el término con "bullicioso". En realidad, un "[bullicio](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6HVdG9T)" es un ruido causado por la concurrencia de mucha gente. Es decir, un "mogollón" es "un mogollón de gente", un "bullicio", un "jaleo". Al final, todos los significados están interconectados.